# How to set individual cell tooltip/bind property to the tooltip for TableColumn in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, tablecolumn

I have a table where I want to display a tooltip for a specific column that correlates to a different value than the cell that the user is hovering over. I know normally, tooltips are set for the exact cell object value or another string. But I want to display a different value that correlates with each

Like in the image shown, I'm displaying a "type" and I want the user to be able to hover over the individual "type" cell to view the "subtype" string as a tooltip. (Like in the image, but I want this to display the actual type and not a dummy string.) Both are defined in the IDisplayLayer Interface.

I need to display the specific subtypeProperty in the tooltip, instead of a string. This subtype needs to be binded like how the normal PropertyValueFactory's bind the data. How can I bind this? Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

[image: image showing tooltip that needs to display "subtype" instead of string]

```
        TableColumn<IDisplayLayer, String> type = new TableColumn<>("Type");
        PropertyValueFactory<IDisplayLayer, String> pvf2 = new PropertyValueFactory<IDisplayLayer, String>("layerType");

        type.setCellFactory
        (
          column ->
           {
             return new TableCell<IDisplayLayer, String>()
              {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                 {
                    Tooltip tip = new Tooltip("This is a tooltip"); //where I need to set the value here
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(item);
                    setTooltip(tip);
                 }
              };
           });
```

Where both are defined: 
public interface IDisplayLayer {

```
String getLayerType();
void setLayerType(String s);
StringProperty layerTypeProperty();

String getLayerSubtype();
void setLayerSubtype(String s);
StringProperty layerSubtypeProperty();
```

}

Comment: It's unclear where the "subtype" you want to display in the tooltip is defined.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about including that. Both subtype and type are defined in IDisplayLayer interface. Included code snippet. Thank you!

Comment: Can the subtype be changed without the type being changed?

Comment: No both are set at the same time when DisplayManager (implementing IDisplayManager) is constructed.

Comment: If possible, it might be easier if you had a `Type` class with a string value and subtype being a property of it; but of course that might not make sense in your context.

Answer (score 1):

Since your cell effectively depends on two properties in the model object, you probably need a table column configuration something like this:

```
TableColumn<IDisplayLayer, IDisplayLayer> type = new TableColumn<>("Type");
type.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));
type.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<>() {
    private final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(IDisplayLayer row, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(row, empty);
        textProperty().unbind();
        tooltip.textProperty().unbind();
        if (row == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setTooltip(null);
        } else {
            textProperty().bind(row.layerTypeProperty());
            tooltip.textProperty().bind(row.layerSubtypeProperty());
            setTooltip(tooltip);
        }
    }
});
```